# SelectedItem в ListView

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

Добрый день, есть коллекция которая заполняется из базы MySQL:

```
while (contains_result.Read())
{
    ItemsForContains.Add(
    new Contains()
    {
        CId = contains_result["id"].ToString(),
        ProfId = contains_result["profId"].ToString()
    });
}
```

Класс со свойствами:

```
public class Contains : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _cid;
    private string _groupid;

    public string CId
    {
        get { return _cid; }
        set { if (_cid != value) { _cid = value; RaisePropertyChanged(); } }
    }
    public string GroupId
    {
        get { return _groupid; }
        set { if (_groupid != value) { _groupid = value; RaisePropertyChanged(); } }
    }

    protected void RaisePropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null) =>
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

Все это дело привязано к ListView (ItemsSource).
Я пытаюсь сделать что-бы при клике по одной из строк ListView мне к примеру выдавало MessageBox с данными именно той строки, на которую кликнул.
Делаю вот так:
Привязка к SelectedItem в ListView:

```
SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItemsContains}"
```

SelectedItemsContains:

```
private Contains _SelectedItemsContains;
public Contains SelectedItemsContains
{
    get { return _SelectedItemsContains; }
    set
    {
        _SelectedItemsContains = value; RaisePropertyChanged();
    }
}
protected void RaisePropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null) =>
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
```

Ну и само событие на клик:

```
private void editProf_MouseLeftButtonUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show(SelectedItemsContains.CId);
}
```

Выводит "Ссылка на объект не указывает на экземпляр объекта.", а если добавляю в метод editProf_MouseLeftButtonUp строку SelectedItemsContains = new Contains(); ошибка пропадает, но выводит просто пустой MessageBox

Comment: а если сделать так: http://pastebin.com/45Y6s7vz ? (это только для отладки, не делайте так в реальном коде)

Comment: Ошибка, та же что и раньше, а если вот так http://pastebin.com/vsNxr1kd, то пустой месседж, так же как и раньше.

Comment: Если я пишу SelectedItemsContains = new Contains(); я же получается этому итему присваиваю пустые значения, может можно как-то выдернуть прямо из коллекции эту строку?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Дело в том, что первый клик лишь только выделяет элемент, а вот второй клик по этому же элементу должен выдавать информацию. Поэтому нужно проверять на `null`, а потом уж выводить.

```
private void editProf_MouseLeftButtonUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    if (SelectedItemsContains != null)
    MessageBox.Show(SelectedItemsContains.CId);
}
```

Comment: Так же:( только теперь если SelectedItemsContains = new Contains(); не создавать он не срабатывает

Comment: `Дело в том, что первый клик лишь только выделяет элемент, а вот второй клик по этому же элементу должен выдавать информацию. ` Это еще кто сказал?

Comment: @Дмитрий Вот это совсем ненужная операция: `SelectedItemsContains = new Contains(); ` у вас же привязка на эту переменную стоит в ListView !

Comment: Удивительно, заработало, вроде бы и не менял ничего, просто студию перезапустил...

Comment: @Дмитрий я посмотрел, вроде ничего такого не заметил. У вас коллекция из БД отображается нормально? Поставьте точку отстанова на вход в метод editProf_MouseLeftButtonUp и посмотрите значение `SelectedItemsContains`, что выдает?

Comment: Да, нормально отображается, спасибо большое, я разобрался уже. Добавил условие как вы написали и перезапустил студию. Без перезапуска не хотела показывать :(

Comment: @Дмитрий очень рад, что все получилось. Кстати, после просмотра вашего кода ряд непрошенных советов :) Вам надо чаще разделять слишком длинные методы на части, каждый метод должен решать только одну задачу, например, извлечение данных из БД и отдавать данные в другой, который уже присваивает значения свойствам для показа наружу. Так проще дебажить, определять где может быть узкое место. И еще, нужно хоть какие-то комментарии вставлять, что метод делает.

Comment: Спасибо, учту :)